# method for vehicle tracking from birdeye perspective given disparity map

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I'm working on a project to detect and track vehicle from above (birdeye) given a stereo camera. With a disparity map I can segment the car which is higher than the ground and calculate it's position by averaging the segmented pixels.

Problem arises when obstacles of same height are placed on the map. Can anyone help me with method apart from optical flow? (I also need the position of a standing car)

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. If you run into a programming question at one step while you are trying to solve it, that would be a better question to ask.

Comment: What kind of tracking mechanics did you try already? Any probabilistic tracking?

Comment: I threshold the disparity value, so there's only depth segmentation